# How can I send mail from localhost by using postifx

Tags: email

Actually I followed [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) and installed Postfix and configured it.  But its not sending mail to the entered email address. with the following command I tried to send email.

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" user@example.com
```

Anything I missed to do?.

Comment: any error message? I hope `user@example.com` is valid mail id?